# There is a way to bypass the 500K documents limit in MongoDB under 32 bits machin?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm working with *`mongoDB`* 2.6.9 under 32 bits machin, and when I want to do a batch insert for my collection which count over than 500.000 documents it crashes, so I'm asking if there is a solution for that and thank you in advance;

Comment: Sharding or upgrading to a 64-bit system are your two main options here.

Comment: This limitation it's not a parameter that I can modify ?

Comment: Wait, I misread.  Why would you do a batch insert of so many documents at once?  What's the total size?  What client are you using?

Comment: It's not the quantity of documents, it's the total size hits 2GB, which is the limitation of 32bit mongodb. You can use sharding to bypass this but as average documents varies, it's kind of tricky to control total size of each shard.